# Appending and clearing a string in C

Tags: c, string, append

I want to constantly add a char to a char* (I've head its the best way to hold a string in C), then, after a certain amount of loops, I want to be able to clear the char* and repeat the process again. How can I add a char to my char*?

Comment: If `str` is your array and `i` is the index of `'\0'` terminator in your array, and `c` is the char you want to append, the normal way is `str[i++] = c;`, assuming you have enough room in the buffer. To start over, just reset `i` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a certain amount of chars then you can use malloc to allocate that amount with the following syntax:

```
char *str = malloc(number_of_chars);
```

You can then add your chars by iterating over your allocated amount like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chars; i++)
{
    *(str + i) = ...; //the source of your chars is unspecified
}
```

If you want to clear your str you can use the function `free` like this:

```
free(str);
```

Hope this helps you somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings must have memory allocated for them. If you want a variable length string, you need to repeatedly re-allocate memory for it as it grows in size unless you know how big it is going to be in advance.

If you know the string is never going to be over a certain size, you can just allocate a buffer of that size with `char *my_str = (char*)malloc(BUFF_SIZE);` and add each char with `my_str[position] = my_char;`. To reset the string, use `bzero(my_str, BUFF_SIZE);`

If your string could potentially have unlimited length, you'll need to keep allocating more memory every time your buffer fills up. After allocating a larger buffer, you then have to copy the contents of the old one in (you can't change the size of a buffer once it's created.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is enough space, you can simply use [`strcat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html), e.g.

```
char *s = malloc(100);
strcpy(s, "Hello");
strcat(s, ",");
strcat(s, " ");
strcat(s, "w");
```

Another way is to maintain an index of the last character and access the characters directly

```
char *s = malloc(100);
int len;
strcpy(s, "Hello");
len = strlen(s);
s[len++] = ',';
s[len++] = '\0';
s[len++] = ' ';
s[len++] = '\0';
s[len++] = 'w';
s[len++] = '\0';
```

If the string's capacity is exhausted, you must [`realloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) the memory to make room for more characters

```
s = realloc(s, 200);
```

Comment: When I say `char *s = malloc(100);` Does that make room for 100 spaces in memory for 100 different chars?

Comment: Yes and no, it makes room for 100 bytes. But you must account for the trailing `0` byte, so you have room for 99 characters.

Comment: What if I also wanted to add a number next to a char in my char*?

Comment: You can use the same technique to add any character, even digits.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn about the strcat (and other) string functions inherent in C.

For example:

```
char x[10];
strcpy(x,"Compiler");
strcat(x,":");
```

You must also understand how C works with null terminated strings.